# "TypeError: can't dup NilClass" in Capybara + selenium driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rubygems, capybara

I tried following code

```
crawler = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
crawler.visit "https://twitter.com" # Error this line!
```

with

```
gem:
  capybara (= 2.2.0)
  selenium-webdriver (3.3.0)
WebBrowser:
  FireFoex53.0
OS:
  Mac OSX
```

then got following Error

```
TypeError: can't dup NilClass

[stack trace]
gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_capabilities.rb:101:in `dup'",
gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_capabilities.rb:101:in `json_create'",
gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:116:in `create_session'",
gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:76:in `initialize'",
gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/w3c_bridge.rb:45:in `initialize'",
gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `new'",
gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `for'",
gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:87:in `for'",
gems/capybara-2.2.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:13:in `browser'",
gems/capybara-2.2.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:45:in `visit'",
gems/capybara-2.2.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:197:in `visit'"
```

url "https://twitter.com" is working when I manualy visit on this FireFox browser.

but capybara's `visit` method is does't work..

Comment: Capybara 2.2 is over 3 years old - Update to the current release.  Also for FF 53 you want selenium-webdriver 3.4.x and geckodriver 0.16.1

Comment: @ThomasWalpole
update gems then resolved!
very thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error (*TypeError: can't dup NilClass*) when trying to use the `selenium-webdriver` gem [as instructed](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#api-example):

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

As [suggested by Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718081/typeerror-cant-dup-nilclass-in-capybara-selenium-driver#comment74488288_43718081), updating the `selenium-webdriver` gem number from 3.3.x to 3.4.x resolves the issue.